# Bootstrap 4 tool-tip appearing from the second hover on a dynamic element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dynamic element on which the Bootstrap tool-tip need to appear upon the hover. So I've used Jquery delegates as below. But the issue is tooltip not appearing on the first hover, but from second hover it is appearing. Can you please point out the mistake?

### HTML for dynamic element

```
 <td scope="col" id="{{this._id}}" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="CLICK TO VIEW">
      <i class="fas fa-eye"></i>
 </td>
```

### Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('body').on('mouseenter', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function(event) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because the first time you hover on the element, the tooltip is initialized and again it shows the tooltip. What you need to do is initialize the tooltip on dom ready.

Comment: @RohitSharma I've used `$(document).ready(function() {})` but the result still unchanged..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried just this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').tooltip({
        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'  // tooltip objects will be delegated to the specified targets i.e. '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
    });
});
```

Read more about [tooltip options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/#options) here.

Comment: Welcome @METALHEAD, Glad it helped.